# Download image/png - RCurl

Tags: r, http, rcurl

I'm trying to use Clearbit.com's free logo API (https://logo.clearbit.com/:domain) to download the a few company logos.

To try out the tool, simply paste https://logo.clearbit.com/nike.com into your web browser.

The goal is to save the Response from a GET request as a PNG file. Here is a an example of the code I'm using, which fails.

```
    library(RCurl)
    url <- "https://logo.clearbit.com/basf.com"
    png <- getURL(url, httpheader = "image/png", ssl.verifypeer = F)
```

This produces the following error message:

```
    Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) : 
    embedded nul in string:'‰PNG\r\n\032\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0\0\0\0\0\b\006\0\0\0Ã>aË\0\0\0\004gAMA\0\0±\vüa\005\0\0\0 cHRM\0\0z&\0\0€„\0\0ú\0\0\0€è\0\0u0\0\0ê`\0\0:˜\0\0\027pœºQ<\0\0\0\006bKGD\0ÿ\0ÿ\0ÿ ½§“\0\0\0\atIME\aß\006\036\022\0228_nn\005\0\0\027$IDATxÚíyx[Õ÷?÷^IW»dË–÷5v\026'qœ•¤$!%$¡P(]\030Z†y™2CK\aZ\006ž–ç-Ó…¶Ó>}g\nÃ¼¥lçi¡e:L\031\030(…°¦¤$$„fOììÞâ}·,YÒ]æ\017+"ŠäÄÄv3É½Ÿ<y\022stîÑ9ß{öó;Âë‡ŸÔ11,â…N€É…Å\024€Á1\005`pL\001\030\034S\0\006Ç\024€Á1\005`pL\001\030\034S\0\006Ç2•‘9­^<r\016ƒ£Œ*#IwQÈu•eüNgèxòÿ’hÁoÏG\024$B±>"ñá\v?—<S(\0êœË\bºËÙÛþ\026£§\025¬WÎ¡¶`mÆo½qd,œßžÇü‚µØ-®¤_W¨‘\003›Q´è…Î§K–I\vÀ#çà·ç‘ï©ÄïÈÏ\030ÆkÏ\005 y`?]¡¦4\177I´RW¸\036«dçP÷{Œ*#ÌÊ]NÐ]Žª)ìïÜt¡óé’eÒ\002(òÎ¢Ä_sÖ0.[\026\0ý‘\016ú#miþ9Î\022¬’þH;Í\003û\001\020\005‘ùùW’ç©à`×f4]M†\027\004‘ «\034€P¬‘Ø\00Ö„ä8K\023Ïj'¦FD+\005ž*|ö º®Ñ>|,-\r\016«—|Ï\f\\6?è:‘ø0¡ã„bý\0Ø-.|ö<¢Ê\b\021%D©\177. p¤g;N«—|O\025.›\017\035\030\036íáäÐá‹¦Öš´\0:C'\bÇ\a\001(ñÏÅiõ¦…q'\004à°z¨+\\(XÆ\n»\177\037ª®$kˆS\031\0160\020é\004Æú\017n9›¡
```

I've searched through the documentation, but I have not been able to remedy this, so please advise.

P.S. This is my first post on stackoverflow, so feel free to pose suggestions on style and general guidelines.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: How about just using baseR: `download.file(url,"myimagename.png",mode="wb")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative to **RCurl** is the new **curl** package of Jeroen Ooms, which provides a modern interface to `libcurl`.

```
## install.packages("curl")
library("curl")
curl_download(url = "https://logo.clearbit.com/basf.com",
              destfile = "~/foo.png")
```

This is the image I downloaded:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
library(RCurl)
url <- "https://logo.clearbit.com/basf.com"
png <- getBinaryURL(url, httpheader = "image/png", ssl.verifypeer = F) # download
writeBin(png, con = tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")) # save
shell.exec(tf) # open file on windows
```

Comment: This allows me to view the png file, but I don't see that is have been saved.

Comment: It's saved in the filename that is stored in the variable `tf` - enter`print(tf)`.

Comment: This does work, but not as seamless as I was hoping. Check out the answer from Gavin above; `curl` just seems to be a little more user-friendly in this case.

Comment: The most straight forward solution would be `download.file`, as mentioned in the comments. I thought you were looking for an {RCurl} solution. But I guess {curl} is the future, and Gavin is much more experienced anyway. :)